# All In One WordPress SEO plugin creates a meta description from the post and joins lines without using any spaces

Tags: wordpress, php

I have a question regarding Worpress All in One SEO pack. It creates description without space to new lines. Here is an example:

```
<meta name="description" content="Welcome to my websiteHere is everything you are looking forOur site is 100% user friendly"/>
```

**Post Content:**

> Welcome to my website
>   Here is everything you are looking for
>   Our site is 100% user friendly

Here **websiteHere**, **forOur** joins without space. Can anyone help me, to get rid of this space-less description.

Comment: Can you double check and make sure your `meta` description wan't keyed without the space at `...ng forOur site is...`?

Comment: Try adding a hard space in your text.  Instead of a space use &nbsp;

Comment: It could be that you use instead of spaces the line-breaks, which are correctly filtered out by plugin

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: Yeah i tried manually doing meta description in a post and that is working fine. But this auto generated meta description is not using spaces in the line-breaks.